# Using concat or append to add an column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what I have pulled in thus far and it ends with not appending correctly
I want to add my count column to
Here's the objective: What are the countries that have more than 4 cities listed in the cities table, and what is the minimum, average, and maximum populations of those countries, as well as the number of cities in each country? Order the result from the country with the most cities to the one with the fewest cities.

```
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://dsa_ro_user:readonly@pgsql/dsa_ro')

connection = engine.connect()

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM cities", connection)

connection.close()

df.head()
import numpy as np
new_frame=df.groupby("country")
new_frame=new_frame["population"].agg([np.sum,np.mean,np.std])
new_frame.reset_index(inplace=True)



 new_df=df.groupby(["country"]).count()
new_df.columns.values[0]= "count"
new_df
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_frame2=new_df.groupby(["count"]).count()
new_frame2
new_frame2.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_frame2=new_frame2[new_frame2["count"]>4]
new_frame2
del new_frame2["population"]
new_frame2
##new_frame2.reset_index(inplace=True)
del new_frame2['country']
new_frame2
```

new_frame=new_frame.append(new_frame2, ignore_index=True ,sort=True)
new_frame
new_frame=new_frame.sort_values(by="count", ascending=False)
new_frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't access your data I have used data from https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities, but based on your code your data should look the same (`country`, `city` and `population` columns):

```
df = pd.read_csv('worldcities.csv')
df = df[["city_ascii", "population", "country"]].rename(columns = {'city_ascii':'city'})
```

Your `new_frame` and `new_df` data frames are good, you have the summary stats in `new_frame` and the city counts per country in `new_df`.

The next step is to filter for countries with more than 4 cities and put that into a new data frame:

```
#create a df of countries with more than 4 cities and remove population column
cities_gt_4=new_df[new_df['count'] > 4].drop(columns=["population"])
```

Now we want to join this data frame with our summary stats `new_frame`, based on country names. We can use pandas' [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to join the two data frames together, based on the values of the `country` column in each data frame (we define based on which columns we want to join using the `left_on` and `right_on` arguments). We are using a left join (`how = "left"`), which means we will only keep rows for `country` values that exist in the left data frame (`cities_gt_4`). This means all country rows with <= 4 cities will be dropped, producing the desired final data frame. Then we sort using `sort_values()`.

```
merged_df=pd.merge(left = cities_gt_4, right = new_frame, how = "left", left_on = "country", right_on = "country")


merged_df=merged_df.sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

Comment: NB, the challenge with [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) is that you need to keep track of your row order and indexes so that the column you add is in the exact same order as the data frame that you are adding the column to. `merge` avoids this by joining directly based on the `country` columns value.